# Custom post type, permalink, add query variables problem

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Doing something wrong, can't figure out what..Any help is highly appreciated for sure!

I have a custom post type which I want to add query vars to in permalink structure..
So far so good....

This is wordking right: 
http://allehondenrassen.nl/kennel?artist=queen&genre=pop

This is not working:
http://allehondenrassen.nl/kennel/queen/pop/

**in my archive-kennels.php I added:**

```
echo get_query_var('artist');
echo get_query_var('genre');
```

**In functions.php I added:**

```
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'dvd_rewrite_rules');
function dvd_rewrite_rules($rules)
{
global $wp_rewrite;
// custom post type name
$dvd_post_type = 'kennels';
$dvd_rule = array(
    // Custom Rewrite Slug = kennel
    'kennel/(.+)/(.+)/?' => 'index.php?post_type=' . $dvd_post_type . '&artist=$matches[1]&genre=$matches[2]'
);
return array_merge($dvd_rule, $rules);
}


add_filter('query_vars', 'dvd_query_vars');
function dvd_query_vars($vars)
{
$dvd_vars = array(
    'artist',
    'genre'
);

return array_merge($dvd_vars, $vars);
}
```

Playing with this for hours but can't see the problem...
Thanks in advance!
Bas

Comment: I have not looked in-depth into your code. But have you flushed your rewrite rules? `Settings > Permalink > Save Changes`

Answer (score 1):

Yes I did, didn't help but thanks anyway!
I fixed it by installing the dump environment plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dump_env/

This way I was able to evaluate all existing rewrite rules.
My custom rewrite rule was conflicting with an existing rewrite rule that WP generated for the custom post type by default.

I changed my rule

```
'kennel/ras/(.+)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=' . $dvd_post_type . '&artist=$matches[1]&genre=$matches[2]'
```

Now it works as it should!
The dump env plugin, this is going to save me some development time in the future ;)
Thanks!

Comment: You should also consider modifying your regex, It's going to behave unexpectedly.  Better: `^kennel/ras/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`